# How can I change phpSpreadSheet version?

Tags: php, version, phpspreadsheet

I´m developing a web application with phpSpreadSheet and I want to change the version. I have the version in the composer:

```
{
    "require": {
       "phpoffice/phpword": "v0.17.*",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.9"
    }
}
```

If I change it there it is enough or do I have to change something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run composer update in the folder where you change the require setting:

```
composer update phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```